# pivoting multiple columns R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

I have this data:

```
    structure(list(classificador = c("classificador 1", "classificador 1", 
"classificador 1", "classificador 1", "classificador 1", "classificador 2", 
"classificador 2", "classificador 2", "classificador 2", "classificador 2", 
"classificador 3", "classificador 3", "classificador 3", "classificador 3", 
"classificador 3"), classe = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("bolha", 
"coral_sol", "cosc_mult", "coscinodiscus", "detritus", "fake_coral", 
"multiples", "org_parts", "organism", "shadow"), class = "factor"), 
    media_entrou = c(0.000181463342477325, 9.11739514644428e-06, 
    0, 0.00710836752524651, 0.0523307152250179, 5.76207054303695e-05, 
    2.31948309497038e-05, 0.000533722409264464, 0.00395244621833009, 
    0.0277347189726644, 0.000511091116817504, 2.78792287970657e-05, 
    0.00167363838758039, 0.00714582937886204, 0.03664291179572
    ), desv_pad_entrou = c(0.000625138593404583, 4.01259397230609e-05, 
    0, 0.00982865377212798, 0.0382102106478645, 0.000197304670837601, 
    0.00015803336539453, 0.00133833325218429, 0.00460178168250652, 
    0.0198204066019173, 0.00560789561914724, 0.000295803787791627, 
    0.0011439791450099, 0.00660048491487252, 0.023022755540947
    ), media_saiu = c(6.31000967592145e-05, 0, 0, 0.0117956025289566, 
    0.00890647892432332, 0.000100059064539586, 0, 0, 0.0587231357033222, 
    0.0639343116405082, 0.00028538070772188, 0, 2.54448072255982e-05, 
    0.0616763969528522, 0.0284492872735916), desv_pad_saiu = c(0.00010828405298676, 
    0, 0, 0.00782886688427178, 0.00460945360308487, 0.000418014988563, 
    0, 0, 0.0258394941887122, 0.0678523075381303, 0.000824409079665752, 
    0, 0.000147663248976053, 0.0346114091736888, 0.0165290142815091
    ), N_ciclos = c(118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 318L, 318L, 
    318L, 318L, 318L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 158L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), groups = structure(list(
    classificador = c("classificador 1", "classificador 2", "classificador 3"
    ), .rows = structure(list(1:5, 6:10, 11:15), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I would to like pivot this data with new columns: `classificador`, `classe`, `E_S`, `media`, and `desvio`. Where `E_S` column has the value name `entrou` accordingly to the columns `media_entrou` and `desvio_entrou` and the value name `saiu` accordingly to the columns `media_saiu` and `desvio_saiu` and the values of columns `media_entrou` and `media_saiu` in the new column `media` and the values of columns `desvio_entrou` and `desvio_saiu` in the new column `desvio`.

Output expected for the first 4 rows:

| classificador | classe | E_S | media | desv | N_ciclos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| classificador 1 | bolha | entrou | 0.000181 | 0.000625 | 118 |
| classificador 1 | bolha | saiu | 0.0000631 | 0.000108 | 118 |
| classificador 1 | coral_sol | entrou | 0.00000912 | 0.0000401 | 118 |
| classificador 1 | coral_sol | saiu | 0 | 0 | 118 |

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `pivot_longer`, specify the regex pattern to capture the groups in `names_pattern` i.e. `^([^_]+)` - match one or more characters that are not a `_` from the start (`^`) and capture  (`(...)`) followed by `_` and capture the rest of characters (`.*`) from the column names which will be the values in the 'E_S' column

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-N_ciclos) %>%
   dplyr::rename_with(~ str_remove(., "_pad")) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), names_to = c(".value", "E_S"),
      names_pattern = "^([^_]+)_(.*)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 30 × 5
   classificador   classe        E_S         media      desv
   <chr>           <fct>         <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 classificador 1 bolha         entrou 0.000181   0.000625 
 2 classificador 1 bolha         saiu   0.0000631  0.000108 
 3 classificador 1 coral_sol     entrou 0.00000912 0.0000401
 4 classificador 1 coral_sol     saiu   0          0        
 5 classificador 1 cosc_mult     entrou 0          0        
 6 classificador 1 cosc_mult     saiu   0          0        
 7 classificador 1 coscinodiscus entrou 0.00711    0.00983  
 8 classificador 1 coscinodiscus saiu   0.0118     0.00783  
 9 classificador 1 detritus      entrou 0.0523     0.0382   
10 classificador 1 detritus      saiu   0.00891    0.00461  
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. Amolst it.
In the E_S column ought to just two names ("entrou" or "saiu").
For example, in result of your code the column E_S has  names "pad_entrou" and "ciclos". Besides that the columns "media" and "desvio" dont match. Is possible to fix it?
Thanks a lot

Comment: @WilsonSouza thanks for the comments.  Can you please show few rows of expected output in your post.  I was thinking that there is some logic missing

Comment: @WilsonSouza Do you want to remove the `N_ciclos` before doing the pivot_longer

Comment: @WilsonSouza i updated the post.  Please check if that helps

Comment: Thanks @akrun the update helps a lot...It's ok don't have the column N_ciclos.